# Get image custom post image size - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code:

```
<div class="content project clearfix">
    <?php
        if( have_rows('galeria') ):
            while ( have_rows('galeria') ) : the_row(); ?>
                <img class="project-item" src="<?php the_sub_field('imagen'); ?>">
            <?php  endwhile;
        endif;
    ?>
</div>
```

The thing is that every `img` ("imagen") has different sizes, and the output I get is:

```
<img class="project-item" src="http://test.local/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/project-5.jpg">
```

As you can see no width or height is set. How can I get the width and height of image on attr?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the `getimagesize()` function - I think it's a `gdlib` function, which is usually installed with any PHP installation:

```
$fileInfo = getimagesize(the_sub_field('imagen'));
```

Which will produce an array similar to this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 800
    [1] => 799
    [2] => 2
    [3] => width="800" height="799"
    [bits] => 8
    [channels] => 3
    [mime] => image/jpeg
)
```

**Use like:**

```
<?php 
$img = the_sub_field('imagen');
$fileInfo = getimagesize($img); ?>
<img class="project-item" src="<?php echo $img; ?>" <?php echo $fileInfo[3]; ?> />
```

**Should produce:**

```
<img class="project-item" src="http://test.local/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/project-5.jpg" width="800" height="799" />
```

Comment: But how can I apply it to the `attr` of the image?

Comment: Yeah, something like that but I'm getting this error: Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in /Users/test/Sites/test/wp-content/themes/theme/single.php on line 8

Comment: The `get_sub_field` function is an advaced custom field plugin function http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/

Comment: The goal is to get an array instead of echoing the image to the page so you need the function that returns this: `Array (0 => http://test.local/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/project-5.jpg)` or something similar.

Comment: Hey what about `get_field('imagen')`? Will that return the image?

Comment: No, `get_field('imagen')` won't return the image because the image is in a `sub_field` not `field`

Comment: Weeeeell, like I say, I am not sure about the functions you are using but you need to be able to have an array returned in order to get the file size on it.